# Iterative Variable Modification (In a Loop) - Python

Tags: python, loops, variables, dynamic, iteration

```
variable_1 = "Dummy String"
variable_2 = "Dummy String"
variable_3 = "Dummy String"

for each in range(3):
    variable_(each+1) = "Another Dummy String"
```

The above is incorrect syntax for a problem I am trying to solve.

The purpose of this code is to append the numbers 1-3, to the end of the variable name, before modifying the contents of the variable.

On the run through of the loop - for the value 0 - the value 0 + 1 (1) should be appended to 'variable_' yielding variable_1.

**My question is:** Is this something that is possible in Python? (Python 2.7.8 more specifically), and/or is there a more practical way to achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 2):

usually, you want to use a list instead of a bunch of different similarly named variables:

```
variables = ['Dummy String'] * 3
for i in range(3):
    variables[i] = 'Another Dummy String'
```

Have a look at Ned Batchelder's ["keep data out of your variable names"](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: I don't believe a list will work for what I'm trying to do.

variables[i] will access the information stored within a list item, but i'm unable to run methods on each list item as an individual variable.

variables[i].configure Vs. variable_1.configure

Comment: You _can_ use `globals()['variable_%d' % i] = 'Another Dummy String'` -- But that only works in the global namespace and it really isn't the right way to do it. . .